# XSLT 2.0 how to add values of a for each group loop

Tags: grouping, xslt-2.0

I am trying to count the number of records in a for loop and the sum of their values (for a particular column). Please find the below code and suggest me.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="CostCentre/PCCode">
                 <!-- variables for each pc code -->
                 <xsl:variable name="chargeRate" select="SpaceTariffGroup/ChargeRate"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="dedicatedArea"
                    select="sum((current-group()[SpaceType/ChargeBackType = $chargeBackTypeDedicatedArea]/(Area*CalculationFactor)))"/>            

                 <xsl:variable name="floorFactor"
                    select="$dedicatedArea div ($totalDedicatedAreaPerFloor )"/>`enter code here`
                 <xsl:variable name="floorCommonArea"
                    select="$floorFactor * $totalFloorCommonAreaPerFloor"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="dedicatedAndFloorCommonArea"
                    select="($dedicatedArea + $floorCommonArea)"/>                     

                 <xsl:variable name="totalChargedArea"
                    select="$dedicatedAndFloorCommonArea"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="totalChargedAmount"
                    select="$chargeRate * $totalChargedArea"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="$totalChargedArea"/>
 <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>   
 <xsl:value-of select="$totalChargedAmount"/>
enter code here
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Will print some thing like this.
100,5000
200,5000
300,5000
400,5000

I want an ouput like this.
100,5000
200,5000
300,5000
400,5000
4,20000 ( this last row is total records,the sum of the values of these records) not sure how can I get it

Answer (score 2):

Well you could store the result of the for-each-group in a variable e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="charges">
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="CostCentre/PCCode">
                 <!-- variables for each pc code -->
                 <xsl:variable name="chargeRate" select="SpaceTariffGroup/ChargeRate"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="dedicatedArea"
                    select="sum((current-group()[SpaceType/ChargeBackType = $chargeBackTypeDedicatedArea]/(Area*CalculationFactor)))"/>            

                 <xsl:variable name="floorFactor"
                    select="$dedicatedArea div ($totalDedicatedAreaPerFloor )"/>`enter code here`
                 <xsl:variable name="floorCommonArea"
                    select="$floorFactor * $totalFloorCommonAreaPerFloor"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="dedicatedAndFloorCommonArea"
                    select="($dedicatedArea + $floorCommonArea)"/>                     

                 <xsl:variable name="totalChargedArea"
                    select="$dedicatedAndFloorCommonArea"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="totalChargedAmount"
                    select="$chargeRate * $totalChargedArea"/>
 <charge>
    <area><xsl:value-of select="$totalChargedArea"/></area>
    <amount><xsl:value-of select="$totalChargedAmount"/></amount>
  </charge>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

then you can process the variable with e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$charges/charge">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(area, ',', amount)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and output the sum with

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($charges/charge/amount)"/>
```